# What is the difference in javax.crypto PKCS1Padding RSA enc/dec and iOS security SecKeyEncrypt with the same padding type

Tags: java, ios, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt AES key using RSA (SecKeyEncrypt) with kSecPaddingPKCS1 on iOS, and then decrypt the key using standard java provider for RSA algorithm (javax.crypto). I'm successfully receiving public key generated by java app, storing it in iOS keychain and the using it to encrypt aes key, but when receiving on the java app - I'm getting well known exception javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero. The same code works when I disable padding (sometimes works). So where is the difference between padding used on iOS and on Java patform ? Can someone give me the answer - I'm struggling with this issue for too long. Lost patience.

The source code. 1) generate symetric key, 2) wrap it using rsa public key from my java app. (Tke public key from is created from modulus and exponent which are send to client by java app) 3) prepare NSData : init with encrypted key, append aes encrypted data , send to java app. Then the java app takes first 128 bytes (encrypted aes key) and tries to decrypt it and here an exception is thrown.

```
 [tools generateSymmetricKey];
NSData* encryptedSymetricKey = [tools wrapSymmetricKey:[tools getSymmetricKeyBytes] keyRef:[tools getPeerPublicKeyRef]];
int option = kCCOptionPKCS7Padding;
NSData* aesEncr = [tools doCipher:data key:[tools getSymmetricKeyBytes] context:kCCEncrypt  padding:(CCOptions *)&option];
NSMutableData * result = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:encryptedSymetricKey];
[result appendData:aesEncr];
```

and the method which is borrowed from CryptoExercise which should work for me imo:

```
- (NSData *)wrapSymmetricKey:(NSData *)symmetricKey keyRef:(SecKeyRef)publicKey {
OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
size_t cipherBufferSize = 0;
size_t keyBufferSize = 0;

LOGGING_FACILITY( symmetricKey != nil, @"Symmetric key parameter is nil." );
LOGGING_FACILITY( publicKey != nil, @"Key parameter is nil." );

NSData * cipher = nil;
uint8_t * cipherBuffer = NULL;

// Calculate the buffer sizes.
cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
keyBufferSize = [symmetricKey length];

if (kTypeOfWrapPadding == kSecPaddingNone) {
    LOGGING_FACILITY( keyBufferSize <= cipherBufferSize, @"Nonce integer is too large and falls outside multiplicative group." );
} else {
    LOGGING_FACILITY( keyBufferSize <= (cipherBufferSize - 11), @"Nonce integer is too large and falls outside multiplicative group." );
}

// Allocate some buffer space. I don't trust calloc.
cipherBuffer = malloc( cipherBufferSize * sizeof(uint8_t) );
memset((void *)cipherBuffer, 0x0, cipherBufferSize);

// Encrypt using the public key.
sanityCheck = SecKeyEncrypt(    publicKey,
                                kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                                (const uint8_t *)[symmetricKey bytes],
                                keyBufferSize,
                                cipherBuffer,
                                &cipherBufferSize
                            );


LOGGING_FACILITY1( sanityCheck == noErr, @"Error encrypting, OSStatus == %d.", sanityCheck );

// Build up cipher text blob.
cipher = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)cipherBuffer length:(NSUInteger)cipherBufferSize];

if (cipherBuffer) free(cipherBuffer);

return cipher;
```

}

One more thing. On the java side I'm using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding cipher instance.

HOW I TRANSMIT PUBLIC KEY:
The public key generated by java decoupled to modulus and exponent then both values are converted to raw byte arrays, and sent, then they are reproduced on the ios client side, converted to the ios keyring compatible format and inserted to the keyring. The public key is correctly transmitted, I have compared both modulus and public exponents on the both sides and they match. the public key is alo successfully imported into keyring on ios (this is accomplished by BasicEncodingRules BER categories). I think there must be something wrong with PKCS1padding padding support - it must differs on both platform (maybe computation related to padding needs some additional stuff on ios).

Comment: Add the Objective-C code where are you doing the encryption

Comment: How do you export the public key on the java side? How do you import it on the iOS side? You might also want to take a look at (or show us) the result of decrypting padded data with RSA/ECB/NoPadding.

Comment: @wojtek-maka: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm actually struggling with the same issue and it took me a while to find this question.